# How to extend View while using a specific XML layout?

Tags: android, layout, view

I want to extends the View class in order to store custom objects in it.
my custom view should be the result of inflating a specific layout.

Right now I'm using this code

```
    public EpisodeView(Context context, final ViewGroup rootView, final CustomObject object) {
        super(activity);
        this.object = object;
        this.context = context;
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.episode_view, rootView);
        initControls();
        setDisplay();       
    }

    protected void initControls() {
        this.textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.customTextView);
...
}
```

My problem is that findViewById allways returns null. The problem isn't comming from my layout xml.
It's more that I don't know how to set my customView with the

Answer (score 2):

You have this error:

```
this.textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.customTextView);
```

which you should change to this:

```
this.textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customTextView);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had a mistake in my code, I just updated it. Sure I can add a View member, but i don"t understand why this.findViewById(...) wouldn't work